# Prevent access to inherited members

Tags: c#

This question might be a bit odd. The scenario is as follows:

- There is an interface for plugins called `IPlugin`
- There is an abstract base class for plugins (which implements the interface) called `PluginBase`
- These are stored inside a class library

Now everyone should be able to create their own plugins by creating a new class library and a plugin class which derives from `PluginBase`.

The `PluginBase` class will provide many public properties which are used from the base tool to communicate with the plugin interface. This is done by reflection; the tool searches for a class which is based on the interface `IPlugin` and creates an instance of that class.

Now the problem is that these public properties are necessary for the plugin mechanism but should not be accessed or changed from the derived plugin class. In short: the user-defined plugin class should not be able to access several public members of its base class `PluginBase`.

Is this possible somehow? I know that I normally should use `private` for those properties (so the derived class can't access them) but as the base class also acts as a plugin interface, this is not possible.

**Solution (based on answers of Fabjan and Luaan):**

```
// basic plugin interface (IPlugin.dll)
public interface IPlugin
{
    // plugin communication interface
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    void SomeMethod();

    // public interface
    string Name { get; }
    void Run();
}

// plugin base class (IPlugin.dll)
public class PluginBase : IPlugin
{
    string IPlugin.SomeProperty
    {
        get { return "Something"; }
        set { /* ... */ }
    }

    void IPlugin.SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something");
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "MyName"; }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// user-defined plugin (MyPlugin.dll)
public class MyPlugin : PluginBase
{
    public MyPlugin()
    {
        // will not work
        this.SomeProperty ...
    }
}

// main assembly
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"path\to\assembly");

    var type = asm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetInterface("NamespaceOfIPlugin.IPlugin", true) != null);

    NamespaceOfIPlugin.IPlugin plugin = (NamespaceOfIPlugin.IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // works as expected
    plugin.SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me like that information shouldn't be on that class. If a class has public properties it isn't allowed to access then it feel like that must be metadata about that class that could maybe be stored elsewhere? Can you give an example of a property that should be on the class but not under control of that class? It might help make the problem and requirements more understandable.

Comment: Are those public Properties comming from the Interface?

Comment: @gsharp Yes the public properties are comming from the interface `IPlugin`. As I said the main assembly will load the plugin assembly (DLL) which contains a user-created plugin class which derives from `PluginBase` and therefore implements `IPlugin`. The main assembly searches for this class, creates an instance and then will access some public properties. The main assembly only knows `IPlugin`. Those public members should not be accessible by the derived plugin class as they should only be used by the main assembly for plugin communication.

Comment: @Chris Even if I put the information in some other meta data class, this meta data must be provided as some public property for the main assembly, so the main assembly can interact with the plugin.

Comment: @Chris An example would be a property which only contains a setter and will control the plugin behavior (e.g. Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, etc). This will be used by the tool to control the plugin. But as it is public a derived class may also change it and this might lead to strange effects as the tool may lose control. E.g. the tool knows when a plugin can be paused or not. The tool won't allow to pause it at other times but the user-defined plugin may abuse this and pause it any time.

Comment: Ok. I think the solution described by Luaan is the right one. Work with PluginBase and not with IPlugin. Explicit implementation doesn't pervent the Developer of a Plugin to access the Methods of IPlugin ... they will look at the Interface definition cast it and use the methods. Developers are evil :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the problem is that these public properties are necessary for the
>   plugin mechanism but should not be accessed or changed from the
>   derived plugin class.

What you try to do isn't really possible because if class implements abstract class - it must know all its members. What you can do is you can do something like this:

1) Add internal keyword for your interface

```
internal interface IPlugin 
{
   int MyProperty1 {get; set;}
   int MyProperty2 {get; set;}
   int MyProperty3 {get; set;}
   void HiddenMethod();
}
```

2) Implement properties/methods that you want to hide explicitly :

```
abstract class PluginBase : IPlugin
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    int IPlugin.MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    void IPlugin.HiddenMethod() {}
}
```

Now you can use all your hidden methods and properties in your main solution via IPlugin interface by casting to it:

```
IPlugin instance = new MyConcretePlugin();

instance.MyProperty3 = 10;
instance.HiddenMethod();
```

IPlugin interface now is not accessible from any other solution (except one that holds it) and therefore same are for all hidden members.

Comment: Ok I was able to test this with some dummy code and it works perfectly. It will "hide" the properties for the derived class (not really hides it but it's not visible in intelli sense or able to change by simply using `this.property`). And as the main assembly directly works on `IPlugin` I don't even need to change the access logic/code. Thanks this was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In my case the interface will remain public as I use it from another assembly.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the properties to be public, don't make them public.

The architecture of your solution seems to be wonky at best. You expect (*require* even) all plugins to implement `PluginBase`, yet you search for plugins based on the `IPlugin` interface. Why? Pick one, and roll with it. There's no rule in the framework that plugins must be searched for based on some interface.

To prevent a derived class from accessing the members of its parents, you use the `private` access modifier. If your plugin manager needs to have access to those values, you must make sure it actually does - for example, you could make the part responsible for working with this data a `sealed` nested class of `PluginBase`.

But in the end, the question is - why? There's little point in trying to *force* the derived classes to avoid accessing those members (why have those members in the first place?). Perhaps it would be enough to have those properties in an interface that would be implemented explicitly? That way you could still use e.g. `((IPluginBase)plugin).SomeProperty`, but not `plugin.SomeProperty`. It's not like they couldn't get to the data using reflection anyway.

Comment: The class `PluginBase` basically provides some logic every plugin needs and therefore should not be implemented by each individual plugin. But for the tool the interface `IPlugin` is enough. It might be possible to create a plugin which only implements `IPlugin` but not `PluginBase` but has to implement the logic from `PluginBase` in some way. This would be fine for the tool as well.

Comment: My goal is not to prevent accessing them in any way (e.g. by reflection) but it should not be easy to do. Someone who implements its own plugin class should only see those members which he should be allow to change and not the others which are used by the tool which communicates with the plugin. There are many properties that are necessary for the plugin interface but for the plugin developer only very few are even useful. And the plugin developer can change values which may cause strange things and that should not happen (at least not in an easy way by accessing some members directy).

Comment: @RobertS. Well, go with the explicit interface implementation, then. Keep the fields `private`, and the properties an explicit implementation of the interface, and the derived classes will not be able to access them directly (they'd need to do something like `((IPluginMetaData)this).SomeMetaData` - nothing too hard, but not too open either; in any case, it declares the intent of accessing something "hidden").

Comment: I guess this would be enough for my case. Will try it out when I got home. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Luaan. Explicit implementation was the correct solution. As Fabjan was quicker, I accepted his answer.

Comment: @RoberS. Really? It shows up as Fabjan's answer being more than half an hour later than mine. Weird.

Comment: Oh you are right, sorry. But I guess his answer shows the solution in a better way and contains some examples. I will upvote your answer of course. Unfortunately I can't accept two answers. :(

Comment: @Luaan and as you describe this is the proper way to do it +1.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) on the methods and properties that only should be available from within the assembly

```
public class PluginBase : IPlugin
{
    // Only accessible within the same assembly
    internal static int x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Not entirely because you can still access all these members using reflection

Comment: Am I able to access/change internal properties with reflection from another assembly?

Comment: yes you can access them using reflection, but you can't override and replace the methods that the pluginbase has as internal. You can also take a look at sealed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx

Comment: @RobertS. There's no way to prevent that ever - everything is *ultimately* open at the reflection level (the assembly reflects perfectly). That said, this is also the case in a non-reflective language - the main difference is how much work this takes, and how well it handles updates.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah I know. It's not about making it impossible to access something. I only don't want to show a huge amount of properties and methods to the developer he doesn't need. Explicit declarations did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InternalsVisibleToAttribute.[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)